# Can I get values from the local storage using Async Storage from React Native?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, react-native

I am new at React Native. There is a native application written in Objective-C for iOS and Java for Android. My task is to add two more screens using React Native. The general solution is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).

The native code already uses a local storage to store permanent data (for example, data about an authorized user). At the same time, React Native uses Async Storage to handle permanent data.

Can I get values from the local storage using Async Storage from React Native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know AsyncStorage is using Dictionary on iOS side and SQLite on android side. Both of which are not accessible in React Native side. You should write a bridge between native side and React Native to in order to allow passing of data between two sides, this https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences library is a good example, it allows React Native access local native shared prefrences and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will now proceed to a decision based on it.

Comment: Is there something similar written for ios? Has anyone tried using [this library](https://github.com/dsibiski/react-native-userdefaults-ios)?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `setItem()` for set data and `getItem()` for get data.
Set data:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'data');
```

Fetch data:

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
```

Asyncstorage in react native : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#docsNav

Comment: I think his problem is that AsyncStorage is not accessible in android side.

Comment: Really Async Storage is not available for Android. But that's not the issue. I already have a ready-made application written in native code that uses local storage.  With the help of Async Storage, I can't get the data of the local storage that is already used by the application. That's why @DNA.h seems to be the most correct answer.